# display density histogram without KDE seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn

I have this code:

```
sns.distplot(X, bins=100, kde=False)
```

that creates this plot:

[image]

If I remove the  kde=False, I get this plot
[image]

How can I get the density histogram, without the line?
I would like to get a histogram, with density values.

Comment: The [distplot documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html) mentions a parameter `norm_hist=` which can be set to `True`. *If True, the histogram height shows a density rather than a count. This is implied if a KDE or fitted density is plotted.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answer as mentioned by JohanC May 2 at 16:48:

From [distplot documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html), set `norm_hist=True`
Then, the histogram height shows a density rather than a count. This is implied if a KDE or fitted density is plotted.